# Get count data monthwise from iso-date mongo-db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have collection `users`.

`users` collection has the data as following

```
{
  '_id' : '5ed52b5fc5a55a0d8556288d',
  'name' : 'Don',
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
},
{
  '_id' : '5ed52b5fc5a5230d8556288d',
  'name' : 'Fabiano',
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
},
{
  '_id' : '5ed52b5fc5a55a0d8500288d',
  'name' : 'Jose',
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
},
{
  '_id' : '5ed51b5fc5a52a0d8500288d',
  'name' : 'Capablanca',
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
}
```

The `Isodate` year is `2020` only.
As we can observe that users are created the following months as below

```
  'Don' -> 'January','Fabiano' -> 'February','Jose' -> 'February','Capablanca' -> 'April'
```

Is it possible that mongodb or moongoose query can get the result as something like or similar to below

```
[
  //key -> month and value -> no of users
 {
   1 : 1
 },
 {
   2 : 2
 },
 {
   4 : 1
 }
]
```

I am using nodejs,express with mongodb and mongoose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use aggregation

```
model.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$createdAt"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $month: "$createdAt" },
      userCount: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: { monthNumber: "$_id" }
  },
  {
    $project: { _id: 0 }
  },
  {
    $sort: { monthNumber: 1 }
  }
])
```

You will get following output

```
[
  {
    "monthNumber": 1,
    "userCount": 1
  },
  {
    "monthNumber": 2,
    "userCount": 2
  },
  {
    "monthNumber": 4,
    "userCount": 1
  }
]
```

Here's a [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XDDH-fzrxiO)